# Laravel is not accepting GET API request without any parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-api

I am making APIs in Laravel version 8.x for a third party system. For this, I have created few APIs and all routes are mentioned in **routes/api.php**

In our system, there are few APIs that can be accessible via GET request, that returns data without any authentication and parameters. Look at the routes below in api.php:

```
//routes/api.php 
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\WebServices'], function() {
    Route::get('event_types', 'EventWs@getEventTypes');
    Route::get('event_type/{event_type_id}', 'EventWs@getEventTypeById');
});
```

Look at the both routes above. The route having segment is working fine with GET request, but the route without any segment is not calling. This is just a simple GET request without any segment or query string.

I am working on Laravel from past few months, but this issue is strange to me. May be there could be some kind of middleware that prevent GET (without segment or query string) route execution. But I am not able to find reason or that unknown barrier.

Have anyone idea about why this happening or I am missing something?

**Please Note that I am using Laravel 8.x**

Comment: the URI `event_types` is the one not working? and what is happening if it "isn't working"?

Comment: @lagbox it is just rendering route from web.php, where I have created universal route that accepts any route and render common page. But, now I got some hint why this happening. In route service provider web.php is processing first then api.php. As web.php has universal route that accept any url upto 2 segments and render that common page. This is the reason why my API request(upto 2 segments) was not processing. Anyway, thanks for showing interest in my issue.

Comment: your catch route is probably catching that since they are based on segments ... please provide that other route you have defined ... that is most likely the issue .... or please feel to answer the question yourself or close it  :-)

Comment: You can list all routes in your app using `php artisan route:list`. That instruction will show you all active routes.